# How to change the language of whole application from the dropdown in Navbar component in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, parent-child, parent

I created a language selection dropdown in my Navbar component. So here is my navbar component:

```
<div>
                <h6>{{ translate("welcomeMsg")}} </h6>
                <select name="lang" v-model="lang">
                    <option value="en">English</option>
                    <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
                </select>
            </div>
<script>
export default {
    mixins: [en, de],
    data() {
        return {
            lang: "en",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        translate(prop) {
            return this[this.lang][prop];
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

So the parent of this component is an Index.vue which is main component in my application.

```
<div id="app">
        <Topnav/>
        <Navbar/>
        <router-view></router-view>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
```

Currently, I am able to change the language in my Navbar component. So according to the selected value in the dropdown in Navbar component, welcomeMsg is changing. What I am trying to do is I want to put this pieve of code to TopBar "

###### {{ translate("welcomeMsg")}}

", and according to the value of the dropdown in Navbar component, I want to change this value.

Can you help me with this or can you give me an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `translate` method inside `Topnav` component.
This method is however defined in `Navbar`, so it's not accessible in `Topnav`.

To use it elsewhere you could create a mixin with this method to import it to any component. I don't recommend this solution though as mixins are making the code messy.

Another solution is to create a component with `translate` method defined inside. Let this component do just that: translate a message passed by prop and render it inside some `div`:

```
<div>
  {{ translatedMessage }}
</div>

<script>
mixins: [en, de],
props: {
  message: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  language: {
    type: String,
    default: 'en'
  }
},
computed: {
  translatedMessage() {
    return this[this.language][this.message];
  }
}
</script>
```

You can reuse this component anywhere in the application. You would still need to pass a `language` prop somehow, possibly the solution would be to use `vuex` store to do this, since language is probably global for entire application.

For easier and more robust solutions I would use vue-i18n, which @Abregre has already suggested in his comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70694821/9463070

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to use this method for everything in the application. So do you think your method will help me with this regard? In effeciency also

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution for a full-scale application and you don't have a problem with dependencies, you could try to use vue-i18n.

It's a plugin for vue that does exactly this for multi-locale websites/apps in Vue.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n

**EDIT**

Then in order to use it globally in your app, you should use vuex.
Keep the language selection state there and then wherever you want to use it, you make a computed function with the state.language getter.
The translate function should be a global registered filter
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: Yes, I checked this one but I dont want to use any plugins